# Google Games Services data is gone after uninstalling app

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-cloud-platform

I've integrated Google Play Services into my app and I'm currently using Leaderboards and Achievements. I lately uninstalled the app and reinstalled it. Now the highscore and achievements are gone. Does this mean that one has to save this "sensible" data via google's cloud save?

thx & regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you uninstall an application, the Android system will delete all data that is private to that application (e.g., *files, shared preferences, databases, and etc.*).

In regards to your question, it doesn't make sense to save data in any type of cloud because it's a time consuming process. It also will not be suitable for offline mode applications.

Another thing to consider is if we are trying to save application data over the cloud, how we can we start the application if/when the internet is no longer available?

Some gaming applications save their high-scores and game achievements in public storage, such as the SDcard. In that case you are less likely to lose the data for your app.  The tradeoff, however, is that in public storage, anyone can delete or modify these files, so take that into consideration.